# Adding libvips to a Rails 7 Docker image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose, vips

I'm new to Docker and trying to create a Dockerfile for this new Rails 7 app. I'm using vips instead of imagemagick for the memory benefits.

and my local machine is a mac so `brew install vips` takes care of my non docker development flow, but it hasn't gone so well using the ruby-vips gem, or installing from source.

Running `$ docker compose up` results in:

```
/usr/local/bundle/gems/ffi-1.15.5/lib/ffi/library.rb:145:in block in ffi_lib': Could not open library 'vips.so.42': vips.so.42: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory. (LoadError)
```

With the following docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - ./tmp/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
  web:
    build: .
    command: bash -c "rm -f tmp/pids/server.pid && bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'"
    volumes:
      - .:/myapp
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

and a Dockerfile:

```
FROM ruby:3.0.1
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y nodejs postgresql-client
WORKDIR /myapp
COPY Gemfile /myapp/Gemfile
COPY Gemfile.lock /myapp/Gemfile.lock
RUN gem install ruby-vips
RUN bundle install

# Add a script to be executed every time the container starts.
COPY entrypoint.sh /usr/bin/
RUN chmod +x /usr/bin/entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["entrypoint.sh"]
EXPOSE 3000

# Configure the main process to run when running the image
CMD ["rails", "server", "-b", "0.0.0.0"]
```

I've also tried installing from source (https://www.libvips.org/install.html) install of using ruby-vips with no luck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TLDR; ruby-vips need `libvips42` installed on your docker image.

Update your Dockerfile to use the following:

```
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends nodejs postgresql-client libvips42
```

PS: run `docker compose down` and `docker compose up --build` to force a rebuild of your docker images.

Comment: Actually, you only need the library binary, so `libvips42`. And you don't need all the packages that debian recommends (they recommend the libvips GUI, for example (!!!), which you will not need on a server), so you can use `apt install --no-install-recommends libvips42`. It gets the download down to around 20mb for libvips.

Comment: @jcupitt You are right going to update my answer.

Comment: The `--no-install-recommends` is really useful too -- without that, the apt-get will download 700mb (!!!!?!??! crazy), with it, it's just 20mb.

Comment: Not working unfortunately, same error.

Comment: @NoobException You run `docker compose down` and `docker compose up --build` ?

Comment: Ahh I left off the build flag. Will mark this as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you're actually installing libvips in your dockerfile. Try this:

```
FROM ruby:3.0.1
RUN apt-get update -qq \
    && apt-get install -y nodejs postgresql-client
RUN apt install -y --no-install-recommends libvips42
WORKDIR /myapp
...
```

However, this will install the libvips that comes with buster, and it's 8.7.x from five years ago (!!). Debian does not move quickly.

I would build current libvips from source. Something like this:

```
# based on buster
FROM ruby:3.0.1

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        build-essential \
        unzip \
        wget \
        git \
        pkg-config

# stuff we need to build our own libvips ... this is a pretty random selection
# of dependencies, you'll want to adjust these
RUN apt-get install -y \
        glib-2.0-dev \
        libexpat-dev \
        librsvg2-dev \
        libpng-dev \
        libgif-dev \
        libjpeg-dev \
        libexif-dev \
        liblcms2-dev \
        liborc-dev

ARG VIPS_VERSION=8.12.2
ARG VIPS_URL=https://github.com/libvips/libvips/releases/download

RUN apt-get install -y \
        wget

RUN cd /usr/local/src \
        && wget ${VIPS_URL}/v${VIPS_VERSION}/vips-${VIPS_VERSION}.tar.gz \
        && tar xzf vips-${VIPS_VERSION}.tar.gz \
        && cd vips-${VIPS_VERSION} \
        && ./configure --disable-deprecated \
        && make -j 4 V=0 \
        && make install

RUN gem install ruby-vips
```

That won't include support for GIF save, or for formats like HEIC or PDF. You'll probably want to adjust it a bit. And of course you should not build packages in your deployment docker image, you'd want to do that in a separate dockerfile.

Hopefully ruby-vips deployment will become more automated over the next few months now that's it's the rail7 default. It's rather manual right now.